# Adding a post type to octopress

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, octopress

I am working on a blog for my personal use and wanted to add a news feature in it.
This feature will show five recent news markdown files that I have placed inside the _news folder. But i am unable to understand how to access the directory using the liquid markup in the template just like it is done for posts in the _posts folder.

Comment: Are you using http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/? I'm not sure what exactly is different when octopress is involved...

Comment: I dont know if octopress uses collections for posts. But there is no collection in the _config.yml. But i think i can use these. Thanks
EDIT: Actually this is finally what i have used please add this an answer so I can mark it as correct. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections) rather than posts. Collections can be iterated through by Jekyll/Liquid using `{% for n in site.news %}`, for the `news` collection.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to create a news type of posts is to do it with a plugin.

But I think your problem can be resolved in a simpler manner, using [categories or tags](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/#predefined-global-variables).

Here I'll explain tag's use, but it's the same with categories.

A post with a `news` tag :

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Post 2"
date:   2015-08-12 18:02:44
tags:
  - news
  - javascript
  - anything else
---
Post 2 content
```

The loop used to get all the news tagged posts :

```
  <ul>
    {% for post in site.posts %}
    {% if post.tags contains "news" %}
      <li>
        <h2>
          <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </h2>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

Comment: This is kind of a workaround using existing things. What if i want a new rake task for this and all. But i really appreciate the answer this is the nearest i have gotten till now.